# How to give customers a .NET core class library?

Tags: .net-core, nuget

I am familiar with .NET framework but new to .NET core. I created a software tool as a class library. Apart from releasing it into **NuGet**, I plan to make it available for download on my website.

For the .NET framework version, I created a **msi** installer to install that class library and all its dependencies into customer's "c:\program files (86)" folder. I make this installer available for download on our website.

**What shall I do with the .NET core version of the class library?** Is there any form of installer I should build? Or shall I just zip the DLL and make the zip file ready for download?

Comment: a nuget package is the preferred mechanism.

Comment: But what is the difference? You just have to select  net core  DLLs  for your installer instead of net framework Dlls. As I understand installation only depends on Window version for exmple

Comment: I thought that .NET core is to be used by other operating systems such as Linux and MacOS, so a msi Windows installer does not make sense?